# Who created Datta Bavani?

Tags: dattatreya

Who created Datta Bavani? Please provide some introduction of the creator.

[image: datta bavani]

Comment: simple google search throw the answer that it is written by **Ranga Avadhuta Maharaj**. http://www.14gaam.com/dutt-bavani-lyrics-and-meaning-gujarati-english.htm Of course if we need a "proof" from scripture for this then I am not sure.

Comment: @AADTechnical Of course you don't need proof from scripture for something like this.  Scriptural proof is only necessary for subjects that are discussed in Hindu scripture, not who the author of a 20th-century Gujarati song is.

Comment: what is "proof" that the link is authentic? how to prove that the link is correct or wrong... since that link is not from "authentic" scriptures.   sometimes Absence of proof  is not proof of absence, Hence I am not posting it as Answer!

Comment: @AADTechnical If you're concerned about whether that information is correct, you may want to double-check it before posting it.  I'm just saying that from the perspective of the site's rules, that link is a good enough source.

Comment: what is mean by double checking? shall i contact Internet authority to validate the site? Is this what we do for every link that is ever posted in the question/answer? Are there any white-listed site for which we do not need "double" checking? If so, who decided this white-listed site? what was the criteria? where should i find such list? so all the ref. should only come from this white listed sites ONLY? TOUGH!!

Comment: @AADTechnical To be clear, was far as the rules of the site go, that link is a perfectly adequate source.  Your answer won't be deleted or anything if you post it.  I was just saying that if for some reason you didn't trust that website, you could try to double check it if you wanted.  But that link is certainly a good enough source as far as the site is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rang Avadhoot Maharaj Created Datta Bavani. He also gave one mantra

Paraspara Devo bhava

means we humans should behave as devas. means we should not harm anybody.

Bhakti should be without sho off.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It is Ranga Avadhoot Maharaj. His samadhi is at Nareshwar(near vadodara) in Gujrat. He was disciple of Swami Vasudevananda Saraswati.

[image: Rangavadhoot Maharaj with his guru Swami Vasudevananda]

Source : [Blog on Rangavadhoot Maharaj](https://indiaspirituality.blogspot.in/2009/01/shri-rang-avadhootji-maharaj.html)

Answer (score 1):

The original Marathi Datta Bavani was created by Sree Paramahansa Vasudevanand Saraswati Shree Ranga Avadhoot Maharaj's Guru